# Optimization on row deletion

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big CSV file (>10000 lines) with data like:

```
126142448.465    320351690.1984   606472348.901 6  130544738.78842  320252387.00343
-3021.759       -2354.621  
743.981    nan        979.988 5  nan        nan       
4131.358         nan
```

In order to reduce the volume of information to work with, I am placing the information in single rows so, after that, I need to delete a lot of rows.
It is taking too much time to delete them. How can I reduce it?

Imported Data File: 
[Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKHKH.jpg)

Reduced Data File:
[Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29X0B.jpg)

On the image it is clear the amounts of empty rows generated. I can not consider that are pair ones as some of the original lines are single.

I have tried to delete the empty rows with no screen activity. But it is taking about 50 second to delete 3000 rows.

After many trials, trying to optimize the code:

```
Dim LastEl As Long
With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsRaw = .Worksheets("RAW")
End With

...

wsRaw.Activate 
LastEl = wsRaw.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
Do Until LastEl = 0
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(LastEl)) = 0 Then
    Rows(LastEl).Delete
    End If
    LastEl = LastEl - 1
Loop
```

The results are OK but the time is not.
Any help?

Comment: I will normally use macro to filter the blank cells, then select visible rows only and then delete. this will save a lot of time rather than looping though each row.

Comment:  I have no words. Sounds simply. I will try it and give some feedback. Thanks

Comment: Doing a Filter would be a long process, instead you can use the Method 1 below, just change the Column name to which you would have applied the filter.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just wondering, but have you tried also using `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` at start of your code?

Comment: Thanks to all. I already try all your ideas. By time: Mikku.Method1 (53''), kevin.Filter (53''), Original loop (1' 4''), Mikku.Method2 (1' 14'') and omegastripes.matrix (1' 34'') on a 6400 lines CSV file. So I will use Method 1 as it is the cleanest one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:** **Instead of a Loop, you can use this line:**

```
wsRaw.Range("A1:A" & LastEl).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
```

**Code:**

```
Dim LastEl As Long
With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsRaw = .Worksheets("RAW")
End With

wsRaw.Activate
LastEl = wsRaw.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).row

wsRaw.Range("A1:A" & LastEl).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
```

Given that Column Blank means the row is blank.

---

**Method 2: Adding all the blank rows to a range and deleting at once.**

```
Dim mysel As Range

Dim LastEl As Long
With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsRaw = .Worksheets("RAW")
End With

wsRaw.Activate
LastEl = wsRaw.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).row
Do Until LastEl = 0
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(LastEl)) = 0 Then

        If mysel Is Nothing Then
            Set mysel = Rows(LastEl)
        Else
            Set mysel = Union(mysel, Rows(LastEl))
        End If

    End If
    LastEl = LastEl - 1
Loop


mysel.Delete xlUp
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with arrays you can significantly improve performance:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim a()
    Dim b()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW")
        a = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Value
        ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1) \ 2, 1 To 8)
        For i = 0 To UBound(a, 1) - 1 Step 2
            For j = 1 To 6
                b(i \ 2 + 1, j) = a(i + 1, j)
            Next
            For j = 1 To 2
                b(i \ 2 + 1, j + 6) = a(i + 2, j)
            Next
        Next
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(b, 1), 8).Value = b
    End With

End Sub
```